# What is this message when somebody wants to send gift money with my item?

Tags: steam

I received the following message on Steam:

> Steam Guard: Your account will be credited the amount of $25..00 USD,
>   it will be available after the exchange. If you refuse the exchange amount will be refunded to the buyer. Sincerely administration SteamCommunity Pay: $25.00 USD
>   Registration number:B65880M 
>   VAT ID: PO22531916 
>   IBLT Number: 26819754
>
> ---
>
> Date: 1/10/15 
>   Time: 11.27 
>   After trade your Steam wallet is active add funds here http://store.steampowered.com/steamaccount/addfunds. If a problem appears, contact https://support.steampowered.com/ © Valve Corporation. All rights reserved. All trademarks are property of their respective owners. Steam Wallet - Add Funds store.steampowered.com Steam Wallet - Add Funds store.steampowered.comS (?)

Is this message legitimate? How should I proceed?

Comment: [Recommended Trading Practices](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8912-WEYU-8454)

Answer (score 28):

It's someone trying to scam you.

There is **no way** to send Steam Wallet credit in the trade system. Anyone suggesting otherwise is looking to take advantage of you.

Comment: Technically, there -is- a way to trade **marketable** items for Steam wallet. You just put your item on the Market for the value they're willing to pay. Steam gets a cut, but it works and prevents chargebacks and such that some scams involve.

Comment: Read the answer again. See where it says "in the trade system".

Answer (score 9):

It is a common form of scam used to trick you into believing that you will get the steam wallet after you give the item to the scammer.

REMEMBER, you CAN'T transfer steam wallet funds. The only way to do so is to give someone a steam wallet code.

Please do not accept the trade offer, you will not receive the wallet fund.

More information here: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=232687419

Comment: "DON'T CLICK THAT LINK! IT COULD BE DANGEROUS! To learn more, please click this link."

Comment: Lol, yeah, some links may be dangerous. But I assure you it is safe.